# Problem installing VirtualBox Guest Additions

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on Windows 10.
I am trying to install VirtualBox Guest Additions. I went to Devices >> insert guest addition CD image.
I can now see the CD image on the favourites list. when I am trying to run the software I am getting the below error.

```
> Verifying archive integrity... All good. Uncompressing VirtualBox
> 6.1.10 Guest Additions for Linux........ VirtualBox Guest Additions installer Removing installed version 6.1.10 of VirtualBox Guest
> Additions... Copying additional installer modules ... Installing
> additional modules ... VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
> VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions
> kernel  modules.  This may take a while. VirtualBox Guest Additions:
> To build modules for other installed kernels, run VirtualBox Guest
> Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version> VirtualBox Guest
> Additions: or VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup
> all VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel
> 5.8.0-38-generic.
> 
> VirtualBox Guest Additions: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log to find
> out what  went wrong VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel
> modules will not be replaced until  the system is restarted Press
> Return to close this window...
```

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/log/vboxadd-setup.log`? Have you restarted the VM? Does it look like everything that should be working is working? A bit more info is needed here ...

Comment: I reinstalled the Ubuntu on VM and now when I do "lsmod | grep vboxguest" i get "vboxguest              45056  5" . and the screen is still small meaning the box guest is not working as intended.

Comment: What version of Virtualbox are you running in Windows?  There are known bugs between Virtualbox version 6.1.10 and Ubuntu kernel 5.8.  If you can, try to upgrade to version 6.1.16 from [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured out that the problem was because of the version conflict.